# Need help grouping a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running a query where I need to join 2 tables, Order table and OrderItem. When I join them it creates a row for each product in the OrderItem table. I only need the OrderItem to check if a column has value. How can I group my results to display only one OrderId?

```
SELECT a.[Id]
  ,CustomerId
      ,OrderTotal
      ,ShippingMethod
  ,AffiliateId
  ,OrderDiscount
  ,OrderSubTotalDiscountInclTax
 -- , b.DiscountAmountInclTax

  FROM Order a JOIN OrderItem b ON  a.Id = b.OrderId
  WHERE AffiliateId = 11 AND b.DiscountAmountInclTax = 0.0000 AND OrderSubTotalDiscountInclTax = 0.0000 AND OrderDiscount = 0.0000 AND OrderStatusId = 30 AND CreatedOnUtc > '2018-07-01'
  ORDER BY a.Id DESC
```

This returns

```
Id   CustomerId    OrderTotal    xxx    xxx    xxx    xxx
1        1             5.00       x      x      x      x
1        1             5.00       x      x      x      x
2        2             5.00       x      x      x      x
2        2             5.00       x      x      x      x
```

I would like to group by the Id or OrderId

```
Id   CustomerId    OrderTotal    xxx    xxx    xxx    xxx
1        1             5.00       x      x      x      x
2        2             5.00       x      x      x      x
```

I know this is probably a nube question, thank you in advance for helping.

Comment: That looks more like SELECT DISTINCT than GROUP BY. Are you sure you want OrderTotal 5.00, and not 10.00?

Comment: Just like the flagged duplicate, you don't really need to JOIN for this at all.   An EXISTS() function in the WHERE clause is the best solution.

Comment: First, do a query to group your "OrderItem" table by OrderID, then do the join with the "Order" Table by CustomerID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `distinct`

```
SELECT distinct a.[Id] , CustomerId ,OrderTotal ,ShippingMethod ,AffiliateId ,OrderDiscount ,OrderSubTotalDiscountInclTax -- , b.DiscountAmountInclTax 
FROM Order a 
JOIN OrderItem b
  ON a.Id = b.OrderId 
WHERE AffiliateId = 11 AND b.DiscountAmountInclTax = 0.0000 AND 
OrderSubTotalDiscountInclTax = 0.0000 AND OrderDiscount = 0.0000 AND OrderStatusId = 30 AND
 CreatedOnUtc > '2018-07-01' ORDER BY a.Id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a group by, should work for you, although typically you would want to do a sum() for it to be meaningful.

```
  SELECT a.[Id]
  ,CustomerId
      ,OrderTotal
      ,ShippingMethod
  ,AffiliateId
  ,OrderDiscount
  ,OrderSubTotalDiscountInclTax
 -- , b.DiscountAmountInclTax

  FROM Order a JOIN OrderItem b ON  a.Id = b.OrderId
  WHERE AffiliateId = 11 AND b.DiscountAmountInclTax = 0.0000 AND OrderSubTotalDiscountInclTax = 0.0000 AND OrderDiscount = 0.0000 AND OrderStatusId = 30 AND CreatedOnUtc > '2018-07-01'
  ORDER BY a.Id DESC
  group by a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, I have not the DB and data, but you can try following the next steps (divide the query in small ones)

> 1. - First do the query to get the "Order" total group by OrderId, I think one order is one-to-one relation with the Customer
> 2. - Do the Join with the Order Table using the OrderID

After this, you can add the order or where to the query

```
    SELECT a.[Id],
            ,CustomerId
      ,OrderTotal
      ,ShippingMethod
  ,AffiliateId
  ,OrderDiscount
  ,OrderSubTotalDiscountInclTax

  FROM Order a JOIN (SELECT SUM(ItemTotalPrice),
                              CustomerId
                              ,ShippingMethod
                              ,AffiliateId
                              ,OrderDiscount
                               ,OrderSubTotalDiscountInclTax
                      GROUP BY b.OrderId) B
  ON  a.Id = b.OrderId
```

Regards